# How do I render JSON or JavaScript object literals as part of my view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have many widgets that can use JSON or JavaScript object literals as their data sources, and this data seldom changes, like the kendo menu below. This menu is hard-coded, and I'd prefer it stayed that way - I don't want my app tp get too chatty just populating menus etc - but I'd like to emit that hard code from my Razor view.

```
$("#view-menu").kendoMenu({
    dataSource: [
            {
                text: 'Save',
                url: '#',
                imageUrl: '@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Save.png")'
            },
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "Employee", new {id = Model.EmployeeId})',
                imageUrl: '@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Cancel.png")'
            }
    ]
});

$(".k-menu a.k-link[href=#]").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('form').first().submit();
});
```

Is there an existing helper I can use to e.g. render a `KendoMenuConfig` object that configures this menu? I would like something like this to replace the above:

```
$("#view-menu").kendoMenu({
    @Html.KendoMenuConfig(blah blah))
});
```

Comment: I don't know that something like that exist, but it is not problem to create your own HTML extensions to cover that logic.

Comment: I haven't used it yet myself but you may be interested in the RazorJs nuget package: http://nuget.org/packages/RazorJS More on the subject from the author here: http://djsolid.net/blog/razorjs---write-razor-inside-your-javascript-files

Comment: @Jesse, thanks, but I question the utility that package a bit. I'm already doing what he does with simple partial views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No write your own html helper

```
@Html.KendoMenuConfig(blah blah))
```

return the string that correspond to your config and it will work, you are actually on the right way.

```
public static String KendoMenuConfig(this HtmlHelper html,.....)
```

include the class that contains this extension in you /View/Web.config at the namespace part.